# how to efficiently/conveniently compute A-inner product (ie. a bilinear form) of many vectors in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I want to compute some thing like `v'*M*v` in Matlab where `v` is taken from columns of a given matrix `A`, which is square and potentially large. ie. `v=A(:,j)`

What is the most convenient and computationally efficient way to do this?
I am thinking of using `bsxfun` and possibly `reshape` but not sure how exactly it will work.

I remember reading a similar post a long time ago. But I really can't locate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way I came up with was a for loop, not the most elegant way. Maybe someone else will think of something better.

```
function Compare(s, v)
M = rand(s);
A = rand(s, v);

%Method 1: for loop
tic
r1 = zeros(1, size(A,2));
for i = 1:size(A,2)
    r1(i) = A(:,i)'*M*A(:,i);
end
dt = toc;
disp(['for loop with ', num2str(size(A,2)), ' vectors of length ', num2str(size(A,1)), ' was ', num2str(dt), ' s.'])

%Method 2: cell functions with anonymous function
tic
Ap = num2cell(A, 1);
r2 = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) x'*M*x, Ap, 'uni', 0));
dt = toc;
disp(['cell functions using an anonymous function with ', num2str(size(A,2)), ' vectors of length ', num2str(size(A,1)), ' was ', num2str(dt), ' s.'])

%Method 3: Vector multiplication
tic
r3 = diag(A'*M*A);
dt = toc;
disp(['vector multiplication with ', num2str(size(A,2)), ' vectors of length ', num2str(size(A,1)), ' was ', num2str(dt), ' s.'])

end
```

Edit: Outputs

TL;DR: For loop is faster for small data sizes, vector multiplication is faster for large data sizes.

```
>> Compare(20, 200)
    for loop with 200 vectors of length 20 was 0.0016883 s.
    cell functions using an anonymous function with 200 vectors of length 20 was 0.0079001 s.
    vector multiplication with 200 vectors of length 20 was 0.0035036 s.
>> Compare(20, 400)
    for loop with 400 vectors of length 20 was 0.0035246 s.
    cell functions using an anonymous function with 400 vectors of length 20 was 0.010177 s.
    vector multiplication with 400 vectors of length 20 was 0.0076295 s.
>> Compare(20, 800)
    for loop with 800 vectors of length 20 was 0.0069367 s.
    cell functions using an anonymous function with 800 vectors of length 20 was 0.022697 s.
    vector multiplication with 800 vectors of length 20 was 0.0075474 s.
>> Compare(20, 1600)
    for loop with 1600 vectors of length 20 was 0.013802 s.
    cell functions using an anonymous function with 1600 vectors of length 20 was 0.037844 s.
    vector multiplication with 1600 vectors of length 20 was 0.029591 s.
>> Compare(20, 3200)
    for loop with 3200 vectors of length 20 was 0.026893 s.
    cell functions using an anonymous function with 3200 vectors of length 20 was 0.078213 s.
    vector multiplication with 3200 vectors of length 20 was 0.084117 s.
>> Compare(20, 6400)
    for loop with 6400 vectors of length 20 was 0.053695 s.
    cell functions using an anonymous function with 6400 vectors of length 20 was 0.15759 s.
    vector multiplication with 6400 vectors of length 20 was 0.3524 s.
>> Compare(40, 1600)
    for loop with 1600 vectors of length 40 was 0.01514 s.
    cell functions using an anonymous function with 1600 vectors of length 40 was 0.040556 s.
    vector multiplication with 1600 vectors of length 40 was 0.028335 s.
>> Compare(80, 1600)
    for loop with 1600 vectors of length 80 was 0.022824 s.
    cell functions using an anonymous function with 1600 vectors of length 80 was 0.053713 s.
    vector multiplication with 1600 vectors of length 80 was 0.047412 s.
>> Compare(160, 1600)
    for loop with 1600 vectors of length 160 was 0.045606 s.
    cell functions using an anonymous function with 1600 vectors of length 160 was 0.096006 s.
    vector multiplication with 1600 vectors of length 160 was 0.052472 s.
>> Compare(320, 1600)
    for loop with 1600 vectors of length 320 was 0.074407 s.
    cell functions using an anonymous function with 1600 vectors of length 320 was 0.1386 s.
    vector multiplication with 1600 vectors of length 320 was 0.19317 s.
>> Compare(640, 1600)
    for loop with 1600 vectors of length 640 was 0.21931 s.
    cell functions using an anonymous function with 1600 vectors of length 640 was 0.36021 s.
    vector multiplication with 1600 vectors of length 640 was 0.24102 s.
>> Compare(1280, 1600)
    for loop with 1600 vectors of length 1280 was 1.6893 s.
    cell functions using an anonymous function with 1600 vectors of length 1280 was 1.8245 s.
    vector multiplication with 1600 vectors of length 1280 was 0.57957 s.
>> Compare(2560, 1600)
    for loop with 1600 vectors of length 2560 was 6.8812 s.
    cell functions using an anonymous function with 1600 vectors of length 2560 was 7.0459 s.
    vector multiplication with 1600 vectors of length 2560 was 1.2919 s.
```